# weight calculation for panel data set r

Tags: r

I have a panel data set like this

```
date        firms   Market cap    waight formula (expected outcome)
12/24/1990   AA      1500           1500/(1500+3000+5000)
12/25/1990   AA      1000           1000/(1000+3000+5500)
12/24/1990   BB      3000           3000/(1500+3000+5000)
12/25/1990   BB      3000           3000/(1000+3000+5500)
12/24/1990   CC      5000           5000/(1500+3000+5000)
12/25/1990   CC      5500           5500/(1000+3000+5500)
```

As the above example shows that I want to calculate weights ( market cap of one firm on a particular date divided by the total market cap of all firms on the same day).  I can find code for this in a big data set. Could you help me in this regards?

Comment: My question is not like the example you show. I want to add all the firm's market cap in the same day. @PoGibas

Comment: can you add expected output?

Comment: The fourth column is the expected output. Thanks. I show it with formulas. @PoGibas

Comment: But doesn't expected answer in given link do that?

Comment: Sorry, I am late in reply. No, I don't think so.  My question is about the panel data setting where date is involved.@PoGibas

Comment: So just group by date